# npm ENOENT error

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I am attempting to install something with npm but every time I get an ENOENT error. When doing `npm install gulp` I get:

```
C:\Users\coope\TextGame>npm install gulp
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace 
it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-
ca3b1f9f9ac5

npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 
for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js

npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 
or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 
or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 
for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js

npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.3: This module relies on Node.js's 
internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to 
graceful-fs@4.x.

npm WARN textgame@1.0.0 No description
npm ERR! path C:\Users\coope\TextGame\node_modules\ansi-styles
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 
'C:\Users\coope\TextGame\node_modules\ansi-styles' -> 
'C:\Users\coope\TextGame\node_modules\.ansi-styles.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\coope\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04- 
07T21_48_09_076Z-debug.log
```

For other modules such as express, I get a similar error except with the bytes module.

I have attempted to install these missing modules with npm but npm can't install anything. Installing the modules manually works but there are too many dependencies for that to be reasonable. How can this be fixed?